# How does one configure networking on OpenStack?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-computing, rackspace-cloud, openstack

I've been playing with Openstack, but I can't get the networking to function correctly. I'm just trying to get a single server going. I can bring up instances, but they get stuck at the BIOS loading screen (which I can see from VNC), and the log tells me that they're searching for an IP address.

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04, if it matters. I'm using Stackops' PPA for all the Openstack packages. Everything's at the latest revisions.

I've caught this post, and it seems really helpful: http://blog.stackops.com/2011/06/13/understanding-stackops-openstack-nova-networking-configuration/#comment-89. The question I have is: how and where are the various networks listed there (green, red, yellow, and blue) configured? What goes in `nova-manage network`, `nova-manage floating`, and `/etc/nova/nova.conf`?

My server has a 10.1.1.x address, and I just want to give any VM's I bring up another 10.1.1.x address so that it's visible on the local network directly. (I can try getting fancier later.) Can anyone give me some example configuration on how to do this? I don't even care if I use DHCP or "flat" networking. (The server has a second NIC and plugs into a managed switch, but I don't want to try VLAN'ing at this point.)

```
root@stack01:~# cat /etc/nova/nova.conf
  --dhcpbridge_flagfile=/etc/nova/nova.conf
  --dhcpbridge=/usr/bin/nova-dhcpbridge
  --logdir=/var/log/nova
  --state_path=/var/lib/nova
  --lock_path=/var/lock/nova
  --verbose
  --s3_host=10.1.1.50
  --rabbit_host=10.1.1.50
  --cc_host=10.1.1.50
  --ec2_url=http://10.1.1.50:8773/services/Cloud
  --fixed_range=10.1.1.0/27
  --network_size=256
  --flat_network_dhcp_start=10.1.1.2
  --FAKE_subdomain=ec2
  --routing_source_ip=10.1.1.50
  --verbose
  --sql_connection=mysql://root:xxxxxx@10.1.1.50/nova
  --network_manager=nova.network.manager.FlatDHCPManager
  --vnc_console_proxy_url=http://10.1.1.50:6080

root@stack01:~# nova-manage network list
network             netmask         start address   DNS            
10.1.1.0/27         255.255.255.224 10.1.1.2        8.8.4.4

root@stack01:~# nova-manage floating list
test-vm-1   10.1.1.120  None

root@stack01:~# euca-describe-images
IMAGE   ari-5c4f6b10    mybucket/ramdisk.manifest.xml       available   public      x86_64  ramdisk     
IMAGE   ami-5baa20a8    mybucket/machine.manifest.xml       available   public      x86_64  machine aki-19a82b1f    ari-5c4f6b10
IMAGE   aki-19a82b1f    mybucket/kernel.manifest.xml        available   public      x86_64  kernel

root@stack01:~# euca-describe-instances 
RESERVATION r-0f02dr00  admin   default
INSTANCE    i-00000014  ami-5baa20a8    192.168.254.3   192.168.254.3   running None (admin, stack01)   0       m1.small    2011-07-25T17:47:57Z    nova
```

As you can see, my instance is coming up with a 192.168.254.x address. I know I've put that range into my configuration somewhere along the line, but I can't find where it's at in my configuration now, so I can't change it!

I'd give you a link to the docs I followed to setup my image, but they've disappeared from the Wiki! ;-)